# What is the easiest way to change a sub directory in the path of a URL, and leave the rest the same?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

We have a Wordpress site that we recently changed the slug for the events and are now using a new path.

For example, the individual events were at https://website.com/event/title , but are now at https://website.com/learn/title.

I need to make sure all link instances of the old url are redirected to the new. What would be the best method for this?

I think I could possibly use some rewrite rules in the htaccess file or something like that, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plugin like [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) will make this pretty trivial. A [regular expression](https://redirection.me/support/redirect-regular-expressions/) for your use would look something like this (make sure to select "Regex" from the dropdown):

```
Source: ^/event/(.*)$
Target: https://example.com/learn/$1
```

Note that performing redirects after WP identifies a 404 is more performant than creating redirects through `.htaccess`. Also some web hosts include a redirection layer that offers the highest performance.